# purpose of custom hook in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was working on a component that has a player with states and that fetches some data. The whole file looked complex with all those states, fetches, useeffects. so I decides to create a custom hook to split the code into another file which make it a lot easier to work with.

The things is that when looking online all the examples I found say that the custom hooks should be created to be used in multiples components, which mine does not, it is only for one component.

So am I using the custom hook correctly or did I use it for something it was not really made for?

thank in advance.

Comment: Its opinionated... In our codebase we extract complex code into hooks even though they are not reusable like you have done.

Comment: hmm so its ok to use it however I want then

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You found it right. If you don't need to use them again anywhere then you're making more work by having custom hook. Just define then in your component for ease. This will also let you know that this component is specific to that code. That is to say not to export and import unnecessarily.

But the question is:

> The whole file looked complex with all those states, fetches, useeffects.

Are you sure you don't need them again?

Comment: Having over 72k points and misleading engineers with opinions is just not right... Especially in Stackoverflow...

Comment: I am sure I wont use it anywhere else because the player is it own thing, so I should avoid code splitting with custom hooks ? I would easily know which is for which component because it keeps the same name with extra "hook" in the name

Comment: @DennisVash what is you advice then ?

Comment: @DennisVash What's your point? What I am misleading to?